# cascading list dropdown

Tags: html, list, drop-down-menu, cascade

How can I create a cascading dropdown list in HTML, so that when an option is selected another dropdown list appears below, leaving the first dropdown and it's selection displayed above? I have four dropdowns to display, one after the other. A jquery slide down would also be nice.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: this is pretty much what I need, but I cant get it to work, maybe as it's jquery mobile? http://jsfiddle.net/Wmxux/

Comment: SO is more "help me fixing my code" than "write code for me".

Answer (score 0):

I looked at jsfiddle link you provided, you should load data from server through ajax when some option is selected. something like this:

```
$('#state_select).change(function(){
  var stateId = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url:...,
    success: function(response){
      //fill city select with data from server
      //then show city select
    }
  });
});
```

Same event handler should be added to city select, etc.

Comment: So I can't make a page locally which will simply display this functionality? It's for a prototype demo so whether it works on the back end is not relevant for now.

Comment: I'm sorry I am missing something here. When I copy and paste the code from js fiddle what I get is nothing like the example shown